# Does DNS lookup to "localhost" return any other host IP address other than "127.0.0.1"?

Tags: networking, dns, localhost, domain-name, nslookup

WIFI's LAN interface(192.168.1.254) is connected to lan-client(192.168.1.68) whose host name is "localhost"  and also WIFI's localhost uses the loopback IP address 127.0.0.1.

While doing DNS lookup to "localhost", it returns both address "127.0.0.1" and "192.168.1.68"

Note : Lan-client is purposefully named as "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

First of all the name localhost is used to access the network services that are running on the host via the loopback network interface. So I don’t think it is a good idea to name a client localhost. But you can maybe change the hosts file, there is a link from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in there.

Comment: Yes. I changed client's name as localhost (192.168.1.68). But will this client's IP address be returned, when we do nslookup to localhost ?